# check if dot is followed by any other regex meta character using REGEX python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Regex to check if `.` in the string is followed by any of the other regex meta-characters ->  `^ $ * + ? { } [ ] \ | ( )`

How to do this?

I'm trying to do something like below:

`foo.bar` -> dot is not followed by any other meta characters, so return false

`foo.*bar` -> return true (because . is followed by *)

`gmail.com` -> return false

`bar.+gmail` -> return true

`bar.` -> return false

I'm very new to regex. Tried to do something like below:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"([.][\^$*+?{}\[\]\|()]+)+")
print bool(pattern.match("foo.*bar"))
```

But it's not correct plz help.

Comment: You must use search() instead of match. See match vs search here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match  And check findall(), too: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp is mostly correct but some characters are excessively escaped in the character class (for example, `|` doesn't have to be escaped when used inside the class).

You need to use `search` method instead of `match`. There's a subtle difference between `search` and `match`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: r = re.compile('\.[\^$*+?{}\[\]|()]')

In [4]: bool(r.search("foo.*bar"))
Out[4]: True

In [5]: bool(r.search("foo.bar"))
Out[5]: False
```

Also, it is better to start learning with Python 3 — version 2 is obsolete.